# How to fix " this moving box under resizable box while dragging up

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

I'm making a resizable box on mobile. 
the problem is that this text under this box is keep moving while dragging the top edge of the box. 
i don't know where to fix?

help me! please.

```
$('#resize').resizable({
    helper: "ui-resizable-helper",
    handles:'n'
});
```

check this problem on the jsfiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/blossom/yt6o34d5/22/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is sort of the expected behavior when resizing with 'n'. It's trying to change the height without changing the position of the other points. If you inspect, you will see that `top` has been changed in addition to `height`.

Answer (score 1):

When you resize from the North (`"n"`), the `height` and the `top` styles are adjusted. If you want to shrink from the top, you want to drop the `top` styling. This can be done with `.css()` by setting it back to `0` or removing it (`""` value).

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/2ov0fbr7/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $('#resize').resizable({
    helper: "ui-resizable-helper",
    grid: [10, 10],
    handles: 'n',
    stop: function(e, ui) {
      ui.element.css("top", "");
    }
  });
});
```

Hope that helps.